# angular js browser back button dosn't work when routing

Tags: angularjs

i have this routing code on my app:

```
var app = angular.module('docFinder', [])

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', 
      {            
        controller: docTable,
        templateUrl: 'partials/finder.html'
      }).
      when('bio/:finderId', 
      {          
        controller: bioCtrl,
        templateUrl: 'partials/bio.html'
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

when i start my app and go to root y click on a link to the second route

once i get there i hit the back button on my browser and it dosn't goes back it only refreshes my current page, any ideas on the problem?

**EDIT:**

***Solution***

```
<tr ng-repeat="doc in providers" ng-mouseover="mouseOverDoc(doc)" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeave()">      
   <td><a href="#bio/{{doc.provider.Id}}"> {{doc.provider.FirstName}} </a></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Your routes look about right, can you show the code you use to go to another page?

Comment: This doesn't work with IE7 (at least), if that's what you're using

Comment: im on chrome, and it dosn't work

Comment: Wouldn't a path such as "/" matches both your route `/` and `/:finderId` (finderId being null). Did you try with a route such as `/bio/:finderId`, just to make sure AngularJS doesn't get confused with the routes?

Comment: just tried, and didnt work, i edited my questio with the changes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use #/ on link. it seems bug on angular js.
for example:

```
 <td><a href="#/bio/{{doc.provider.Id}}"> {{doc.provider.FirstName}} </a></td>
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem to be a bug to me.

AngularJS provides two configuration modes for $location service to control the format of the URL in the browser's address bar.

1. Hashbang Mode (#!)
2. HTML5 Mode

This can be resolved if you set the configuration to HTML5 Mode
using `{ html5Mode: true }`.

Comment: It seems like it shouldn't correctly handle both in either mode. Non-hash links should fail in hashbang mode, and hash links should fail or only trigger a search change in html5 mode.